# Problem With Lead Assignment Rules

Tags: assignment-rules

I have created a single (there are no others) lead assignment rules. It routes incoming leads from Hubspot (ebooks, demo requests, case study downloads etc) to our lead gen person.

The rule works correctly in the sense that it is assigning the correct leads 100% of the time. But it always assigns them to our lead generation person's manager. I cannot figure out why. Anyone have thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried going into Setup -> Logs -> Debug and add the web2lead lead creator to the debug log, to see what's happening?

Comment: Note there is in `Setup | customize | lead | settings` a value for 'default lead owner' who will get any leads not assigned by an assignment rule.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue on cases, I believe the reason the cases are assigning to the manager because they are the default case owner, the assignment rules aren't firing because this is a field that has to be ticked on the page layout, to check this use the lead history tracking on the owner field if this is being assigned using assignment rules you will see an entry with of owner change at creation with the word Assignment in brackets if you are not seeing this, the assignment rules are not working